# find span of infinite subspace of $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

I am trying to solve below problem. but I'm uncertain my solution and also have question about finding basis of infinite vector space

> Let $S=\{h \in C[0,1] : h(0)=0\}$ and $T=\{h \in S : \int_{0}^{1}h(x) =0 \}$. For the subspace $T$, Show that $span\{T,1,x\} = C[0,1]$.
>
> HINT : for $f \in C[0,1]$, find $a$ such that $f(x)-f(0)-ax \in T$

Attempt:  $\forall f \in C[0,1]$ define $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)-ax$  ($a\in \Bbb R$)

Let us find $a$ which satisfies $\int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx=0$

For convenience, let $c=\int_{0}^{1}(f(x)-f(0))dx$

then suppose,

$$\int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}(f(x)-f(0)-ax) dx=0$$
$$c-\frac{1}{2}a=0$$
$$a=2c$$

so $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)-2cx \in T$

thus $span\{T,1,x\} =C[0,1]$

Q .
I think the above proof is true intuitively because $g$ is made of any $f \in C[0,1]$ except for the element of $span\{1,x\}$. so $span\{1,x\}$ can fill the gap of  $C[0,1]\setminus T$. but I need more sophisticated proof of how $g$ can span $T$

Comment: Your proof is fine. You show that each $f \in C[0,1]$ can be written as a linear combination of an element of $T$, $1$ and $x$. Why do you need a "more sophisticated proof"? (and, btw., what do you mean by "more sophisticated?)

Comment: @gerw ah I understand why is the proof sufficient because  we can make any $f$ through linear combination of $g$  $1$ and $x$ . thank you for help!!